# Only allow a certain domain to access my Django backend

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx

I'm currently developing an application which consists of a React frontend, which makes frequent requests to a Django backend. Both the React and Django applications are running on the same server.

My problem is I wish to hide my Django backend from the world, so it only accepts requests from my React application. To do so, I've been trying several configurations of `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in my Django `settings.py`, but so far none of them seem to be successful. An example route that I wish to hide is the following:
https://api.jobot.es/auth/user/1

At first I tried the following configuration:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS=['jobot.es']`
but while this hid the Django backend from the world, it also blocked the petitions coming from the React app (at jobot.es). Changing the configuration to:
`ALLOWED_HOSTS=['127.0.0.1']`
enabled my React app to access the backend but so could do the rest of the world. When the Django backend is inaccessible from the outside world, a get request from https://api.jobot.es/auth/user/1 should return a 400 "Bad Request" status.

The error I get when the React app fails to request data from the Django backend is the following:
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.jobot.es/auth/login' from origin 'https://jobot.es' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`, but in `settings.py` I have allowed all Cors origins with `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`.

The url of my React application is https://jobot.es, while the url for the Django backend is https://api.jobot.es, but as both apps are hosted on the same server both urls resolve to the same ip address. On the server I'm using Nginx to redirect traffic accordingly to either the React app or the Django backend.

In case it is of any help, here are the Nginx configurations for the React app (first) and the Django backend (second):

React app Nginx configuration

```
server {
     
       server_name jobot.es www.jobot.es;
       
       access_log off;

       location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';      
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jobot.es/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jobot.es/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot





}
server {
    if ($host = jobot.es) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


     
       server_name jobot.es;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Django backend Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name api.jobot.es;

    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jobot.es/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jobot.es/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.jobot.es) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name api.jobot.es;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

I also attach the GitHub repositories for both the React App and the Django backend in hopes that they may be of any help.
React App:
https://github.com/PaburoTC/jobot
DJango Backend:
https://github.com/PaburoTC/JoboBackend

Thank you in advance <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "hide" the Django application, since the React app, which would be contacting the Django backend, is running in users' browsers (i.e. in the outside world).

In other words, there is no separate "React application" connecting to your Django API backend, it's just the user's browser first requesting jobot.es, then api.jobot.es.

You *could* check for the referer header, but it has no real security benefit at all.